# Show that the function $g(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)\cos(xt^2)dt$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\in L^1(\Bbb R)$. We want to show that the function $g(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)\cos(xt^2)dt$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$.

**Attempt.** Let $a\in\Bbb R$. Given $\epsilon>0$ we want to find $\delta>0$ such that $x\in \Bbb R$ and $|x-a|<\delta$ implies $|g(x)-g(y)|<\epsilon$. Note that
$$|g(x)-g(a)|=\left|\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\big(\cos(xt^2)-\cos(at^2)\big)dt\right|\leq \int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(t)||\cos(xt^2)-\cos(at^2)|dt$$
It seems that the last integral goes to $0$ as $x$ goes to $a$. But how can we find such a $\delta>0$? Thanks!

Comment: Are you allowed to use DCT?

Comment: Do you know the dominated convergence theorem ?

Comment: Yes! I know it and I am allowed to use the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|f(t)| |\cos(xt^{2})| \leq |f(t)|$. Hence DCT shows that $x_n \to x$ implies $g(x_n) \to g(x)$.